# Go through other pages in jqgrid(navigate)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

```
var jqDataUrl = "@Url.Action("transaction")";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#jqgProducts').jqGrid({
        url: jqDataUrl,
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: ['Name', 'Reson', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'No of Days'],
        //columns model
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', align: 'left', width:175},
            { name: 'Reson', index: 'Reson', align: 'left' , width:75},
            { name: 'Start Date', index: 'StartDate', align: 'left', width:100 },
            { name: 'End Date', index: 'EndDate', align: 'left',width:100  },
            { name: 'No Of Days', index: 'NoOfDays', align: 'left', width:75 },
        ],
        pager: $('#jpProducts'),
        rowNum: 10,
        sortname: 'StartDate',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        height: '100%'
    });
```

this is my jquery grid. Its working. But I cant go through the page of grid. It views only first page. arows of the bottom of grid not working. I cant go to the next page. Can anyone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your code in the action `@Url.Action("transaction")` ignore the `page` and `rows` which jqGrid sent to the server. You use `datatype: 'json'` without `loadonce: true` option. So you have to implement **server side paging** of data.

See for example [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) for code example which shows how to implement server side paging, sorting and searching.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to implement server side paging/sorting you can use `loadonce:true` option.

But if you want to implement server side sorting, firstly you method `transaction` should be ready to accept the following parameters

```
public ActionResult transaction(string page, string rows, string sidx, string sord)
{}
```

If you have worked with JqGrid before you will no doubt be familiar with the default parameters passed to any ajax request: “page”, “rows”, “sidx” & “sord”.

These parameters correspond to current page, records per page, sort column, and sort order respectively.

Here is an article on : [How to use JqGrid with ASP.NET MVC](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-use-jqgrid-with-asp-net-mvc/) also there is an another great article by Phil Haack on this [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/13/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx).

[This article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=618), will also be useful when implement server side paging and sorting for any thing.